# Android AppCompat revision 21 force Holo theme

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-theme

in my project I was using appcompat-v7 (revision 20), and my project was targeting android API level 19 (KitKat), so I could use Holo theme. I accidentally updated "Android Support Library" to revision 21, so I had to change the target in manifest to API level 21 (Lollipop).

Because of this, my app's default theme changed to Material (e.g. checkboxes are green). Is there a way to force using Holo theme again?

### Manifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="my.package"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        --- activities & receivers ---
    </application>

</manifest>
```

### Style.xml:

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    </style>


    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: Ideally, there's a way to do this. My guess is that there will not be. If you are using Android Studio, you could just change your `compile` statement for `appcompat-v7` to something lower (e.g., `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'`). If you are using Eclipse, unless somebody publishes an older edition of the regular library project, you might need to try using [my AAR to Android library project converter](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/03/consuming-aars-eclipse.html) to take the older AAR for Android Studio and get something usable from Eclipse.

Comment: Also, FWIW, keep tabs on [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77709), assuming that you weren't the one who filed it. :-)

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare! Unfortunately I'm using eclipse, so i'll try to use your AAR converter to restore the previous version of support library.

Comment: Side question: How do you get green checkboxes with Material design? Mine are black on pre-21 devices and custom colored on 21+.

Comment: I don't know, I have the Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar theme, maybe there is (or was, the library has been updated) a setting there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this problem by downloading the "Android support repository" and by converting the .aar project to a library using @CommonsWare converter.

Comment: You are probably using Eclipse same as I do, so I've started recently manually converting the AARs into Eclipse library projects and maintaining them on GitHub (https://github.com/dandar3/android-support-v7-appcompat, see Releases) for myself and others to use (you can use SVN if scared off by Git/eGit learning curve).

Back to your problem, if you want something specific from appcompat v21 but don't don't want to target API 21, you can probably remove res\values-21 and change to target API 19.

Comment: Yes, i tried this solution, but it's not that simple. If you look at /res/values/themes_base.xml, for instance, you can see that all styles have been modified to support Material design. So if you switch back to API level 19 you'll get a bunch of errors and missing dependencies on attributes, even if you delete values-21!

Comment: You're quite right - sorry, my suggestion was based on v21.0.0-rc1 (have used a modified version to work with API 19) but I see quite a few things have changed between that and release.