# Any way to maintain Holo theme while targetting lollipop/v21 of the SDK?

Tags: android

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26441834/android-appcompat-revision-21-force-holo-theme), and my guess is "no" - still there are some detailes I'd like to get clear. Here is the result of an example settings screen before and after upgrading to SDK v21 and targetting it:

**Before upgrade (target SDK 19)**

[image: Holo theme]

**After upgrade (target SDK 21, on 21-device)**

[image: Material on v21]

**After upgrade (target SDK 21, on 19-device)**

[image: Material on v19]

The application is using the following theme pre-upgrade:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"/>
```

..and the following theme post-upgrade:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/topbar_background</item>
    <!--<item name="colorPrimaryDark">#0F0</item>--> <!-- System status bar -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/vg_theme_color</item>
</style>
```

So the question is really

- How do I either get Holo theme on a v19 device post-upgrade (v21), *or*
- How do get theme-colored checkboxes and titles on v19 devices post-upgrade

Basically I don't like the flat, black check box design.

Answer (score 0):

Have your activity's style's parent inherit from the holo theme by default, and then on API > 21 devices, tell that same style to inherit from the app compat material theme. You can do this by using a styles.XML file in a res/values-v21 folder.

If you notice on Kit Kat, the material gmail app still uses Holo preferences.