# Using 4.x fashioned actionbar with appcompat v22

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

In our project we used version 20.x from android support-libs:

- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+
- com.android.support:support-v4:21.+

We build the project using build-tools version 21 and targetSDK 21:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'
}

defaultConfig {
  applicationId 'com.example.android'
  minSdkVersion 15
  targetSdkVersion 21
}
```

Our app uses a actionbar with this look and feel:
[image]

Now we would like to upgrade the

- com.android.support:appcompat-v7
- com.android.support:support-v4

to version 22. Unfortunately our Actionbar (Toolbar) now looks like new Material Design:
[image]

Is there an (easy) way to let the new toolbar look like old-fashioned 4.x actionbar?

**Update:**
I found a similar issue here, but the accepted solution is to do not update appcompat: [Android AppCompat revision 21 force Holo theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26441834/android-appcompat-revision-21-force-holo-theme)

Comment: Why would you want to do this? You are going against style guide lines. Users will not be pleased.

Comment: It's not part of discussion, but why is it against styleguides to keep the exisiting holo theme of an existing app? Upgrading a whole app from holo to material is a huge effort. A mixture of holo app and material actionbar is a really bad idea.

Comment: **1)**"why is it against styleguides to keep the exisiting holo theme of an existing app" `You should not be using holo, you should be using Material Design from App Compat.` **2)** "Upgrading a whole app from holo to material is a huge effort" `Not at all. In fact, it is much easier with Material Design.` **3)** "A mixture of holo app and material actionbar is a really bad idea" `I never suggested that. See number 1.`

Comment: I do not find any relevant information, which tells me that I should or have to use Material Design for an existing app. Please lets get back to topic and lets keep a technical perspective on this topic.

Comment: Start here: https://developer.android.com/design/index.html. You will have to continue to use the older APIs to keep the old look and this is a technical perspective. You are just trying to go against Google's style guidelines for the latest version of Android.

Comment: You do not answer my question. Where is the relevant information that I have to use Material Design for existing apps? Google itself does not implement Material in its apps completely. Again, this is an existing app. The effort for changing to Material Design is currently to high (New concept, new design, new icons, check the style of each ui element/view, development, qa). It is not done by just changing the toolbar. I definitely know that Material Design should be used, but currently it is not possible in this project.

Comment: Also, the other difference between the new style and the old style is the ActionBarToggle placement. Just use the default one that comes with the NavigationDrawer example. It will correctly sized and placed, simply open Android Studio -> New Project -> Select the Navigation drawer.

Comment: If you do not have any further hints for my topic, then please do not respond. Thank you!

Comment: "Google itself does not implement Material in its apps completely." Where do you get your information? Look at Google Play, Google has almost completed converted all of their existing apps to Material Design.

Comment: If you do not have any further hints for my topic, then please do not respond. Thank you!

Comment: You can't force Holo when if are using AppCompat theming.

Comment: Thanks! This will help me. Maybe I could now get some time and money from my customer to switch to Material Design. ... And like you said: "Google has ALMOST completed converted ..."

Comment: Please read my comments, it does not take long, just update your `styles.xml` and get the correct image for the NavigationDrawer. I can help you make the switch. Just update your question.

Comment: Thats the work for the toolbar. But the whole ui needs a rebrush.

Comment: Christopher, I have the exact same problem. Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: @arne.jans I am sorry. I did not find a solution yet. We finally upgraded our look & feel to material design. Of course you could try to build your own toolbar, but this makes it hard to upgrade to a newer Appcompat-version in future, I guess.

Comment: @Christopher thanks for your answer, I will try to fix the issue, and keep you posted, if you are still interested in a possible solution.

Comment: Of course, I am interested. :)